# Creating MySql Restore script before deletion from database

Tags: mysql, database

Creating MySql Restore script before deletion from database without using database backup

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SackOverflow is an English language site

Comment: FYI - The original question was **Creating MySql Restore script before deletion from database**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason that you couldn't use the Import and Export wizard from MySQL Workbench to accomplish this?

From the workbench, highlight the desired table and right click.
Select Table Data export wizard and follow the prompts.